# insertAfter a div in Angular 2 to a dynamically created element

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 2.0.0 and I want to insert a div after an element which is dynamically created from a jQuery plugin https://springstubbe.us/projects/demos/jquery-multiselect/. I tried to insert it after that element is created using jQuery's insertAfter() function. But now (click) event in appended div is not working. I replaced (click) with 'onclick' but then it's giving error "checkPreSelectedTrade is not defined". Also [(ngModel)] is not working.

Here is the div I want to insert after the element '.ms-search' in the plugin.

```
<div class="float-left">
   <input (click)="checkPreSelectedTrade('construction', $event.target.checked)" [(ngModel)]="isFirstChecked" type="checkbox"><span>New Construction w/ Site Work</span>
   <input (click)="checkPreSelectedTrade('interior', $event.target.checked)" [(ngModel)]="isSecondChecked" type="checkbox"><span>Interior Fit-out</span>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about creating a component with `selector: 'div'` and adding it the same way as your dynamic component? This way it will be added after the dynamic component (as sibling)

Comment: dynamic div is created by jQuery function in the component class and it's not itself a component. It's created when I call a public method containing plugin configuration.

Comment: Does it need to be added by jQuery? What's actually the problem with adding it using jQuery. Actually if you want to add above HTML dynamically `(click)` or anything else that is Angular specific won't work at all. Angular only processes HTML when it compiles components, but not when HTML changes dynamically. If you want that you still need to create a component that you can add dynamically.

Comment: $('select[multiple]').multiselect({columns: 5,placeholder: 'Select',selectGroup   : true,search        : true}); 
This is configuration for initializing that jQuery plugin and after its initialization, I append my div. Is there any other way to make it work?